# How can I read the attributes of a .DLL file using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I want to read the comments of a .DLL file:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In conjunction to nobugz answer, here's a detailed MSDN document on [`FileVersionInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.aspx).